# How do I check the order in which Keras' flow_from_directory method processes folders?

Tags: python, deep-learning, keras

When doing transfer learning, I am first feeding the images through the bottom layers of the VGG16 network. I am using a generator function.

```
datagen = ImageDataGenerator(1./255)
generator = datagen.flow_from_directory(
    train_data_dir,
    target_size=(img_width, img_height),
    batch_size = 32,
    class_mode=None,
    shuffle=False
)
model.predict_generator(generator, nb_train_samples)
```

I am setting the class mode to none, because I only want the data output. I am setting shuffle = false, because I want to feed the predicted features later here, and match them up with the ground truth category variable:

```
train_data = np.lead(open(file_name, 'rb'))
train_labels = np.array([0] * NUMBER_OF_ITEMS_FOR_ITEM1 +
                        [1] * NUMBER_OF_ITEMS_FOR_ITEM2 +...
                        [n-1] * NUMBER_OF_ITEMS_FOR_ITEMN
```

The problem here is that I don't know in which order the files are read. How can I find it out? Or even better yet, how can I just avoid having to guess the correct order? I am asking because I am almost certain that the low prediction accuracy has to do with labels not matching up.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I looked into the [source code](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/keras/preprocessing/image.py). I should note that since I posted this question, Keras was updated to version 2.0. So the answer is based on that version.

ImageDataGenerator inherits from DirectoryGenerator. In it, I find the following lines:

```
    if not classes:
        classes = []
        for subdir in sorted(os.listdir(directory)):
            if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(directory, subdir)):
                classes.append(subdir)
    self.num_class = len(classes)
    self.class_indices = dict(zip(classes, range(len(classes))))

    def _recursive_list(subpath):
        return sorted(os.walk(subpath, followlinks=follow_links), key=lambda tpl: tpl[0])

    for subdir in classes:
        subpath = os.path.join(directory, subdir)
        for root, _, files in _recursive_list(subpath):
            for fname in files:
                is_valid = False
                for extension in white_list_formats:
                    if fname.lower().endswith('.' + extension):
                        is_valid = True
                        break
                if is_valid:
                    self.samples += 1
    print('Found %d images belonging to %d classes.' % (self.samples, self.num_class))
```

Note line 3 where it says "sorted(os.listdir(direcectory, subdir))". The generator traverses all folders in alphabetical order.

Later on the definition of a _recursive_list uses the same logic on substructures as well.

So the answer is: Folders are processed in alphabetical order which somehow makes sense.

Answer (score 3):

Good question, add a `print` statement to the `keras/preprocessing/image.py` in the `next` method in inside the `DirectoryIterator` class: Here is the relevant code which iterates over a list of filenames. You would of course have to rebuild `keras` from source.

```
for i, j in enumerate(index_array):
   fname = self.filenames[j]
   print(fname) # add this to see the current file being accessed

   img = load_img(os.path.join(self.directory, fname),
                  grayscale=grayscale,
                  target_size=self.target_size)
   x = img_to_array(img, data_format=self.data_format)
   x = self.image_data_generator.random_transform(x)
```

However to avoid all that pain this example on the keras [docs](https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/) page suggests that to ensure the consistency one should follow this pattern.
Pass train and validate generators of the same template to the `model.fit_generator` function.

```
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
        rescale=1./255,
        shear_range=0.2,
        zoom_range=0.2,
        horizontal_flip=True)

test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        'data/train',
        target_size=(150, 150),
        batch_size=32,
        class_mode='binary')

validation_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        'data/validation',
        target_size=(150, 150),
        batch_size=32,
        class_mode='binary')

model.fit_generator(
        train_generator,
        samples_per_epoch=2000,
        epochs=50,
        validation_data=validation_generator,
        num_val_samples=800)
```

Comment: Thank you, puttonspectacles. I am now running the above code on one of my laptops. The reason, I started going down that path was that I have not been able to figure out how to use the code above with K-fold cross-validation. The code above assumes that I have a folder with validation files. Any ideas there?

Comment: hmmm not really @Thornhale, in my models I accept the validation metrics as a good approximation of model's generalization. And cross-validation is prohibitive for deep learning models for of the length of training time for each model.

Comment: if your model trains fast enough, you could split your data in to multiple directory and could use use the `fit` method instead of the `flow_from_directory` and use `KStratified` from sklearn on the in a loop over data that you read in.

Comment: if your must read the data in from disk: you could attempt to split your data into multiple directories. and do a loop over the directories.

Comment: What about the transfer learning case, where I am first passing my data through a convolution net without dense top layers first - only once. The output is then stored without labels. I am no longer reading from the original file the next time I train the top layer as in this tutorial (which is the reason I have to somehow regenerate the labels): https://blog.keras.io/building-powerful-image-classification-models-using-very-little-data.html

Comment: In the tutorial it was easy though: There were only 2 cases. Dogs and cats, and each data set was the same size.

Comment: ahh, I see the trouble now, recreating the labels for the features from the VGG16 models could be a hassle. In the tutorial the assumption (since there was not shuffling and given that the different classes are in libraries) he just counted the number of items in the direction in the order of the directory structure (cats the dogs)

Comment: I suggest that you open a separate question that details the structure of your directory with the (after the VGG16 training)